# Which file transfer protocol will support Linux-like file names with NAS?

Tags: 21.04, ftp, file-sharing, nas, smb

I am using Ubuntu 21.04, and I need use Nautilus to transfer files between Ubuntu and a NAS.

The NAS supports AFP, FTP, and SMB  transfer protocols.

Therefore, I can only use the following paths in Nautilus to access the NAS:

- `afp://<user>@<nas>/<path>`
- `ftp://<user>@<nas>/<path>`
- `smb://<user>@<nas>/<path>`

I am using ext4 in Ubuntu, and I have many files that use Linux file paths (including files with special characters such as ":" or "&").

Which one of these three available file transfer protocols will allow me to transfer Linux-style path names (with special characters) between Ubuntu and the NAS?

Note that internally the NAS uses an ext4 file system, so storing the files is not an issue-- just transferring them.

Comment: What options are available for configuring the server? It seems samba can be made to work with special characters: https://serverfault.com/q/124611/229499

Comment: The NAS actually prevents me from making changes. If I modify any files in the / (root) directory on the NAS server, it will automatically overwrite them with default values on the next reboot. If this did not happen, I would have simply enabled ssh for all users, and used `ssh://<user>@<nas>/<path>` in Nautilus. (This worked flawlessly on the older NAS model I had). I'm sure I could "hack" the NAS and prevent the overwriting, but I would rather not do that.

Comment: Then I guess you should tar the troublesome files and put the tar files there.